# HTMLTextBlock for Windows Phone 7

Tags: html, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am trying to include a html textbox into my windows phone 7. I see some [sample code here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2008/03/17/continuing-support-for-simple-html-display-in-silverlight-htmltextblock-sample-updated-for-silverlight-2-beta-1.aspx). The problem is that the HTMLPage class doesn't exist in windows phone 7, or more exactly, the System.Windows.Browser does not exist. Do anybody know an alternative for this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you need to include HTML in a page but not in a WebBrowser control?

Comment: Because the WebBrowser will catch all the horizontal scroll event, it is my most concern with. I know there is someething called HTMLTextBlock for web like this: http://cesso.org/Samples/SilverlightHtmlTextBlock/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I struggled with this for all the same reasons, and eventually came up with a solution. I need to show a bunch of these inside a ListBox for my [Septic's Companion app](http://social.zune.net/redirect?type=phoneApp&id=69ee6f98-d4e2-df11-a844-00237de2db9e). Right now my solution only deals with bold or italic (as that's all I cared about) but it would be easy to modify it to deal with more. First, into my ViewModel I wrote a routine to return a TextBlock given an HTML string.

```
private TextBlock MakeFormattedTextBlock(string shtml)
{
    TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
    Run temprun = new Run();

    int bold = 0;
    int italic = 0;

    do
    {
    if ((shtml.StartsWith("<b>")) | (shtml.StartsWith("<i>")) |
        (shtml.StartsWith("</b>")) | (shtml.StartsWith("</i>")))
        {
            bold += (shtml.StartsWith("<b>") ? 1 : 0);
            italic += (shtml.StartsWith("<i>") ? 1 : 0);
            bold -= (shtml.StartsWith("</b>") ? 1 : 0);
            italic -= (shtml.StartsWith("</i>") ? 1 : 0);
            shtml = shtml.Remove(0,shtml.IndexOf('>') + 1);
            if (temprun.Text != null)
                tb.Inlines.Add(temprun);
            temprun = new Run();
            temprun.FontWeight = ((bold > 0) ? FontWeights.Bold : FontWeights.Normal);
            temprun.FontStyle = ((italic > 0) ? FontStyles.Italic : FontStyles.Normal);
        }
        else // just a piece of plain text
        {
            int nextformatthing = shtml.IndexOf('<');
            if (nextformatthing < 0) // there isn't any more formatting
                nextformatthing = shtml.Length;
            temprun.Text += shtml.Substring(0, nextformatthing);
            shtml = shtml.Remove(0, nextformatthing);
        }
    } while (shtml.Length > 0);
    // Flush the last buffer
    if (temprun.Text != null)
        tb.Inlines.Add(temprun);
    return tb;
}
```

Then I just needed a way to build this into my XAML. This may not be the very best solution, but I first made another routine to return a StackPanel containing that TextBlock with the text I wanted.

```
public StackPanel WordBlock
{
    get
    {
        StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
        TextBlock tbWord = MakeFormattedTextBlock("<b>" + Word + "</b>: " + Desc);
        sp.Children.Add(tbWord);
        return sp;
    }
}
```

To bind this to a visible control, I then made a DataTemplate for my ListBox which simply read the entire StackPanel out of my view model.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="WordInList2">
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding WordBlock}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

As I say, there may be parts of this that aren't done as elegantly as they might be, but this did what I wanted. Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 6):

Hey I converted the [SilverlightHtmlTextBlock](http://dlaa.me/Samples/SilverlightHtmlTextBlock/) to WP7 [Here.](http://musicm122.blogspot.com/2011/10/open-source-projects.html) I
haven't tested it for terribly complex cases and blows up on dtd tags but, it does the job for simpler html cases and sounds like what you were looking for.

Answer (score 4):

WebBrowser can render html.

[How to: Display Static Web Content Using the WebBrowser Control for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431811%28VS.92%29.aspx)

Comment: I do know, but I don't want to use WebBrowser for many reasons: - The UI is harder to change and the event gesture is harder to deal than the HTMLTextBlock

Comment: @vodkhang: There is no such thing a "HTMLTextBlock", you've got work with what you've got.  Using the WebBrowser control is the  only current way to display html content in a WP7 app.

Comment: uhm, actually, I think of something like this http://cesso.org/Samples/SilverlightHtmlTextBlock/