# Display mixed HTML content without WebBrowser? (issues with ScrollViewer)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I want to display some HTML content in my WP7 application. I use the WebBrowser and it works very well. However, my WebBrowser is inside a ScrollViewer because I have some contents that are not HTML in the same page. So, I made my WebBrowser not scrollable and with a fixed height. But the control can't be higher than 2048px and I have some contents that are more than that. Therefore, it doesn't show the entire page and the text is cut.
Here is the code :

```
<ScrollViewer>
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <Image Height="240" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="{Binding ImageStretch}" Width="Auto" Source="{Binding Image}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Credit}" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap" IsHitTestVisible="False" />         
    <phone:WebBrowser Width="Auto" IsScriptEnabled="True" ScriptNotify="WebBrowserScriptNotify" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
</StackPanel>
```

And here is a screenshot of the problem:
[image: WebBrowser problem]

So, is there any alternative to the WebBrowser control or is there a workaround ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

There is no alternative as far as I know, however, the solution to this similar question includes a simple algorithm for converting HTML into TextBlocks:

[HTMLTextBlock for Windows Phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505642/htmltextblock-for-windows-phone-7)

Comment: thanks for your answer but I don't only have text, I also have things such as iframe, image, ... that can not be converted to TextBlock.